# Solution for the Finite 2D Potential Well - Rotational Symmetry

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, wavefunction, schroedinger-equation, potential

I was searching for the  eigensolutions of the two-dimensional [Schrödinger equation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schr%C3%B6dinger_equation)

$$\mathrm{i}\hbar \partial_t \mid  \psi \rangle = \frac{\mathbf{p}^2}{2m_e}\mid  \psi \rangle + V \mid  \psi \rangle$$

where the potential is given by
$$V(\rho, \varphi)=\begin{cases} V_1 & \rho < R \\ -V_2 & \rho \geq R \end{cases}$$

using a space representation and [cylindrical coordinates](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/CylindricalCoordinates.html), $V_i \geq 0$.

I would be happy if someone could point me to a reference or even give the solution here.

Thank you in advance
Sincerely

Robert

#### Request to close the question

As I can see in the comments, questions of this kind seem to be **inappropriate**.
The eigensolutions are given by something like
$$\psi_m(\mathbf{r},t)=e^{\mathrm{i}(m\varphi-\omega_m t)}\begin{cases} a_m J_m (k_{m,1} \rho) & \rho < R \\ b_m K_m (k_{m,2} \rho) & \rho \geq R \end{cases}$$
where the $a_m$ and $b_m$ can be calculated from the steadiness of $\psi$ and its spatial derivative in $R$. Furthermore, $k_{m,1/2} = \frac1\hbar \sqrt{\pm\,2m_e(\hbar\omega_m - V_{1/2})}$.

I am sorry for any inconvenience.

Comment: Write $p^2 = (d/dx)^2$ in cylindrical co-ordinates. Assume $|\Psi>$ can be written as a product $ \Phi(\rho)\chi(\phi)Z(z)$ and the equation splits into three. Standard separation of variables.

Comment: What do you mean by "solution". Do you actually need stationary states?

Comment: @space_cadet: thank you for the insight. I think I am capable of solving the system myself and it is clear that solutions will have the form $J_n(k\rho)e^{\mathrm{i} (n \varphi - \omega_n t)}$ e.g. for $\rho < 0$. But I am safe to assume the solution is already known, so a nice reference is what I am looking for :)

Comment: @Kostya: I am not sure I got what you mean. Isn't in classical QM it always possible to make an exponential ansatz in time of the form $e^{-\mathrm{i}\omega_n t}$ such that $\mathrm{i}\hbar\partial_t \rightarrow \hbar \omega_n = E_n$? I guess, one could call this stationary. Greets

Comment: @Robert Filter: I just want to note that your question is not well-defined al least from mathematical point of view. Either you set initial conditions, either you have to say that you are interested in states with definite energy. And then your actually solving the stationary equation $\hat{H}\psi=E\psi$

Comment: @space_cadet: why not make an answer of your comment? :)

Comment: At this point it seems like just a math question, really - you're basically just looking for the solution of a known differential equation. All the physics is done.

Comment: @Kostya: Ok, now I get you, of course you are right. For an initial value problem would have to find the eigensolutions and expand $\psi (\mathbf{r},t=0)$ in it :)

Comment: @David Zaslavsky: I agree but I guess its perfectly fine to have it formulated like this. I could add some physical motivation but I think it is not necessary in this case :)

Comment: @Kostya: Ok, I changed the question. Searching for eigensolutions seems to be the right terminus, I suppose :)

Comment: This is a standard homework problem for an undergrad QM course. Do we really want questions like this and answers to them on MO?

Comment: @Jeff Harvey: I am sorry to have been posting the question. I thouhght it is ok asking for a nice reference to a basic example.

Comment: @Robert no need to apologise. I think this question is fine here, and I'd give you a reference if I had one in hand. Have you tried *Cohen-Tannoudji*? (there are 2 volumes) http://www.amazon.com/Quantum-Mechanics-2-vol-set/dp/0471569526

Comment: @Bruce: Thank you for the reference, I will have a look :)

Comment: [thread concerning the on/off-topicness  of "mathematical solution" questions](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/q/293/97)

Comment: Although there is some disagreement on the exact reason, there seems to be a consensus that this particular question is off topic here, so I'll close it.